# Is there a way to boot vista with multiple different configs?

Tags: windows-vista, video

I'd like to have a separate config with the majority of services disabled to devote the cpu to video playback. These configs should be separate for better usability.

Answer (score 0):

Separate users with logon scripts to stop services.